# why isn't this URL rewrite working?

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the "real" link:

```
   domain.com/show_shop.php?id=4
```

This is the rewritten:

```
   domain.com/show_shop/4
```

I use the later because I have this in my .htaccess:

```
  RewriteRule ^show_shop/([0-9_]+)$ show_shop.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

But it doesn't work for some reason. Will not this rewriterule give what I want?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^new_ad$ new_ad.php [NC] // WORKS FINE!
RewriteRule ^kategori/([0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ browse_cat.php?cat_gr=$1&p=$2 // WORKS FINE!
```

Comment: This is no way shape or form a security question.

Comment: Is show_shop the start of the line? i thought it would be 'domain'.

Comment: The 'id' parameter isn't passed along. When I try to fetch it like this: $id = $_GET['id'] I get null, it doesn't exist...

Comment: Than it’s certainly due to MultiViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *show_shop* is called but the URL parameter is not set, it could be due to [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try to disable it.

Comment: Gumbo, check my edit again, if it is multi views, then please tell me how to turn it off...

Comment: @Camran: Follow the provided link: “`MultiViews` […] can be set with an `Options` directive […] in .htaccess files.”

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/show_shop/([0-9_]+)$ /show_shop.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Also, if possible, you can see the log of what's happening if you turn these on in your VirtualHost:

```
 #warning, slows server perf
 RewriteLog "/var/log/apache/rewrite.log"
 RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the .htaccess